# If $f$ is $C^{1}$ and $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|f'(x)| = \infty$ , prove that $f$ cannot be uniformly continuous

Tags: analysis, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

I'm looking for help with a proof that I still cannot figure it out. Here is the statement:

"If $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $C^{1}$ and $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|f'(x)| = \infty$ , prove that $f$ cannot be uniformly continuous."

I know that if $f$ is $C^{1}$ and $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|f'(x)| = \infty$, $f$ cannot be Lipschitz. So I tried to prove that if $f$ is uniformly continuous $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is Lipschitz, because if it were true, if $f$ is NOT Lipschitz would mean $f$ is NOT uniformly continuous, and the proof would be resolved.

However, uniform continuity does not imply Lipschitz.

Comment: Wait, that statement sounds very false (take a function with oscillations which get steeper and steeper, but smaller and smaller).

Comment: Perhaps the author intended to assume $\lim_{x\to\infty} |f'(x)|=\infty$ instead? If the derivative is unbounded on a compact set instead, obviously the result will fail, as @D.Thomine suggested.

Comment: Thank you you both for your asnwers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not true. Consider the function
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin(x^5)}{x} \,.$$
with $f(0)=0$. Then, it is easy to see that $f \in C^1$ and since $f$ is vanishing at infinity it is uniformly continuous.

But 
$$f'(x)=\frac{5x^5\cos(x^5)-\sin(x^5)}{x^2}$$is clearly unbounded as $$f'(\sqrt[5]{2n\pi})=5\cdot (2n\pi)^\frac{3}{5}$$

**Note** If $\lim_{x \to \infty} |f'(x)|=\infty$ as Ted Shifrin suggested, then the claim follows immediately from the Mean Value Theorem. Indeed, if you assume that $f$ is uniformly continuous, then there exists some $\delta$ such that $|x-y|< \delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<1$. Apply the Mean value theorem on $(z,z+\frac{\delta}{2})$ and take the limit as $z \to \infty$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: I think $f(x)=x^2$ is the simplest example..

Comment: Thank you @N. S. for your answer. You all might be right, the author (my teacher) has probable made a mistake, it wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: I just would like to get clarified why $sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\frac{5x^{5}cos(x^{5}) - sin(x^{5})}{x^{2}} = \infty$. @N. S.

Comment: @Empty: I don't understand. $f(x)=x^2$ is *not* uniformly continuous on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Hallow: To answer your last question: Take the sequence $x_n = \root5\of{2\pi n}$.

Comment: @Hallow I already explained in the answer why is unbounded: its value at $\sqrt[5]{2n\pi})$ is $5\cdot (2n\pi)^\frac{3}{5}$, which can be made arbitrarily large.

Comment: @Empty  $f(x)=x^2$ is NOT uniformly continuous..

Comment: @TedShifrin I can't understand the question. $f\in C^1$ such that $f$ is not u.continuous but $\sup |f'(x)|=\infty$. Is it?

Comment: @Empty To show that the claim is wrong you need an example of a function which IS u..c, $C^1$ and for which the derivative is unbounded. So you need an example which IS UNIFORMLY CONTINUOUS.

Comment: @N.S. Ok..I misunderstand the question.. Now I got it. Thanks